# weblogic temp directory in jsp web application

Tags: java, jsp, weblogic, temp, tmp

How can I get access to temp directory on weblogic server from my jsp web application (in scriptlet) to keep temporary files, which can created by my application?
Where this weblogic temp directory physically stored on physical drive?
Thanks!

Comment: why do you need to access weblogic files by scriptlet. It not a good way.

Comment: @erencan scriptlet because i want to quick test this opportunity, but i don't understand when app is deployed, where this app can store temp files

Comment: Normally everything is under `<domain home>/servers/<server name>/tmp` but I'm not sure I understand exactly what you need

Comment: @Display Name is missing - thanks for comment, what i need - I assume there is some good programming style where the application stores its temporary files in some temporary directory and does not refer to this directory as a directory on disk, may be I am wrong and there is no such style